# How can I request attribution removal from documentation edit?

Tags: support, documentation, attribution

So I made a stupid mistake and on the spur of the moment I edited [Hello World example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/193/introduction-to-python/728/hello-world#t=201607271952103808633). Now I get annoying +5 rep few times a day even though my edit has been completely obliterated (and it shouldn't be accepted in the first place, or rolled back).

Since it feels ridiculous I would like to ask for a removal of my attribution. Is there any official procedure or should I simply use [contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) form?

Comment: A dev will probably have to do it manually. I don't believe there is any tool to do this yet. We've never had any sort of tool to remove names from *edits* because it's not something that ever comes up.

Comment: I keep seeing +5 -5 +5 -5 as a user presumably clicks upvote unupvote upvote unupvote (an easy way to annoy 45 users)...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the contact us form. I have no idea how we'll accomplish this, but we'll figure it out within 6-8 weeks.

Alternately, wait & see if we fix the accounting such that you don't get rep for edits like that.

Comment: Let's say I don't mind waiting and rep reversal is just fine by me but I still believe there should exists a  mechanism to address requirements like this in general. It is the right guaranteed by the license after all, isn't it?

Comment: If somebody's edit is wiped out by a subsequent one (doesn't even matter for better or for worse) it's a reasonable wish to get disassociated from the post.

Comment: For accounting purposes, it would be nice if we could do this automatically, @PM77-1. However, that may not be feasible. Just don't know right now.

Comment: This sounds like a hard problem.  What if I make an edit to a post and then someone makes another edit that rewords some of what I wrote.  Then someone else comes along, splits my text up and moves things around.  In the end, perhaps my original ideas are all still there, but they have been reworded, reordered, and rehashed so much that the system thinks my contributions are no longer valid. At what point do we draw the line and say I no longer get credit for the contribution? While I agree with the underlying sentiment, it seems like it may just lead to more problems later.

Comment: OK, the latest changes improved situation but I still get +1 which doesn't make sense for no-contribution :/ Do I miss something here?

Comment: No, unfortunately the heuristics aren't perfect @zero323. However, we do now have a functional rollback (removes authors as contributors) for use in the future, and a functional "disassociate" tool for fixing up the past - so go ahead and send us a note if you want yourself removed from the contributor list here.

Comment: @Shog9 I tried using contact form for this, but I guess it didn't went through. Could check this please? TIA.

Comment: I found the ticket & poked it with a broom, @zero323. Should be done.